# File I/O in the Python 3 C API

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-c-api

The C API in Python 3.0 has changed (deprecated) many of the functions for File Objects.

Before, in 2.X, you could use

```
PyObject* PyFile_FromString(char *filename, char *mode)
```

to create a Python file object, e.g:

```
PyObject *myFile = PyFile_FromString("test.txt", "r");
```

...but such function no longer exists in Python 3.0.
What would be the Python 3.0 equivalent to such call?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it the old(new?)-fashioned way, by just calling the io module.

This code works, but it does no error checking.  See the docs for explanation.

```
PyObject *ioMod, *openedFile;

PyGILState_STATE gilState = PyGILState_Ensure();

ioMod = PyImport_ImportModule("io");

openedFile = PyObject_CallMethod(ioMod, "open", "ss", "foo.txt", "wb");
Py_DECREF(ioMod);

PyObject_CallMethod(openedFile, "write", "y", "Written from Python C API!\n");
PyObject_CallMethod(openedFile, "flush", NULL);
PyObject_CallMethod(openedFile, "close", NULL);
Py_DECREF(openedFile);

PyGILState_Release(gilState);
Py_Finalize();
```

Comment: Isn't there any other way to do it? This seems quite cumbersome compared to the example shown in the question.

Comment: What is `"ss"`?

Comment: About "ss", from PyObject_CallMethod documentation:
The C arguments are described by a Py_BuildValue()

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://docs.python.org/3.0/c-api/file.html) claims the API is:

```
PyFile_FromFd(int fd, char *name, char *mode, int buffering, char *encoding, char *newline, int closefd);
```

Not sure if that means it's not possible to have Python open the file from the filename, but that should be trivial to do yourself, in C.