# PyFile_Type replaced by ..?

Tags: c, cpython, python-3.2

I'm tyring to compile [Yenc](https://bitbucket.org/dual75/yenc) for Python 3.2. I noticed that gcc complained about a non-declared function `PyString_Type`, so I replaced it with its replacement `PyBytes_Type` as according to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/c-api/string.html).

However, gcc also complained about an undeclared function called `PyFile_Type`. I googled a bit and found:

```
Python 3.x replaces the PyFile_Type extension type 
with an abstract interface and specific implementation types. 
Unfortunately it doesn't make any of this directly available 
with a C level api.
```

[source](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/25e3f2cee879/PYTHON3)

I am by no means a C-programmer, which leaves me unable to solve this issue. What should I do to solve this?

Edit: [output of compilation](http://pastebin.com/n6BZ5iuc), [_yenc.c](http://pastebin.com/9HHxA8Gt)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, PyFile_Type has been replaced by something not even remotely similar in Python 3, and you'll have to either modify the code yourself or wait for the maintainer to do that.  If you're not a C programmer, it'll likely have to be the latter.  [The documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/c-api/file.html) states that rather than wrapping FILE*'s, Python 3 now wraps low-level I/O, in this case file descriptors and read()/write().

Comment: I don't think it (python-yenc) is alive anymore, so I'm going to fiddle with C myself following [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898136/file-i-o-in-the-python-3-c-api).

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using PyFileIO_Type, however you have to declare it before. (Original is located in _iomodule.h inside the Python sources):

```
extern PyTypeObject PyFileIO_Type;
```